# Cannot call model method from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I've got model named `ProfileLastLocation` and I've got controller named `SinglesAroundController`. My controller have such action:

```
  def in_area
    box = Geocoder::Calculations.bounding_box([params[:cLat], params[:cLng]], params[:distance])
    in_area = ProfileLastLocation.within_bounding_box(box)
    render in_area.to_json
  end
```

When controller action is called - I get error

```
undefined method `within_bounding_box' for #<SinglesAroundController:0xb4f107fc>
```

When I copy rest of code to error console - it works. So i bet `ProfileLastLocation` model is not accessable from my controller.

My model code is

```
class ProfileLastLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SglTablePrefix
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :profile_setting, through: :user
  has_one :profile_mandatory, through: :user
  has_one :profile_optional, through: :user

  scope :available, -> { joins(:user).where("sgl_users.online = ?", true) }

  def self.persons_in_area(cLat, cLng, distance)
    box = Geocoder::Calculations.bounding_box([cLat, cLng], distance)
    in_area = within_bounding_box(box)
      .joins(:profile_mandatory)
      .joins(:profile_optional)
    in_area
  end


  geocoded_by :city, :latitude => :latitude, :longitude => :longitude



end
```

(I'm using `geocode` gem). I've tried both to define it as `self.` method and without `self.`

Also - error shows that my Controller does not have given method, while I'm trying to call it on model, not on controller.

How can I access this model and methods of it from given controller?

Comment: Can you post your model code please.  It'd throw an error saying it couldn't find `ProfileLastLocation` if that wasn't accessible.  I'm assuming you've defined it as an instance method, you're trying to access it as a class method.

Comment: Updated with model code. I've cutted out not related methods of it. Missing method is part of `geocode` gem so it's not coded by me in code.

Comment: Well, the error says that you are trying to call `within_bounding_box` on your controller, and not on the model. Try restarting rails, maybe it's some stale code left.

Comment: Does the `geocoder` gem define `within_bounding_box` as a *class method* for your `ProfileLastLocation` ActiveRecord class? Or does it make it an *instance method*? You're calling it as a class method.

Comment: Did you try ::ProfileLastLocation? Can you post a more complete code for the controller?